# Ajax atravez de la etiqueta <a> href

Tags: html, jquery

Deseo eliminar una fila de Mysql atravez de un enlace  ,de esta manera me sale muy bien `<a href='eliminar.php/?dato_eliminar=` pero la pagina se recarga. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con AJAX y la etiqueta `<a>` o la etiqueta `<button>`?

Aquí el código que genera los botones eliminar para cada registro de MYSQL :

```
    $.getJSON('cargar_materiales.php', {param1: 'value1'}, function(json, textStatus) { 
$.each(json, function(index, val) {
$(".tabla_materiales").append("<tr>"+"<td>"+val.id+"</td>"+"<td>"+val.nombre+"</td>"+"<td>"+val.codigo+"</td>" +"<td>"+val.precio+"</td>" +"<td>"+val.descripcion+"</td>" +"<td>"+  "<a href='eliminar.php/?dato_eliminar=" + val.codigo +"'>Eliminar</a>" +"</td>" + "</tr>")
});
});

});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, reemplaza la imagen con el código escrito, esto no es bien recibido en la comunidad; por otro lado, la solución a tu problema es el uso de [**event.PreventDefault()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadiremos una clase al `<a>` y añadiremos `javascript.void(0)` para quitar el evento default de la etiqueta `<a>`. También crearemos un atributo llamado `code-val` para almacenar el codigo:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' code-val="+val.codigo+" class='btneliminar'>Eliminar</a>
```

Luego cuando clickamos en la clase del botón cogeremos el valor del atributo `code-val` y lo enviaremos a la url. Cuando se ejecute ejecutar la parte del `success`, la cual no has especificado

```
$(".btneliminar").click(function(){
  var dato=$(this).attr("code-val");
  $.ajax({
     url:"eliminar.php",
     data:{dato_eliminar:dato},
     success:function(result){
         //Aquí poner el codigo luego de ejecutarse
     }
  });
});
```